# Better understanding javascript's yield

Tags: javascript, generator, koa

I have the following code in my Koa app:

```
exports.home = function *(next){
  yield save('bar')
}

var save = function(what){
  var response = redis.save('foo', what)
  return response
}
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following object was passed: "OK"`

Now, "ok" is the response from the redis server, which makes sense. But I cannot fully grasp the concept of generators for this kinds of functions. Any help?

Comment: Which redis package are you using?  I would guess that you are using the regular redis npm module, which expects a callback.  try co-redis which returns a promise.

Comment: oh, no I am using coRedis, the code for the connection is the following: `var redis   = require("redis"),
    coRedis = require("co-redis"),
    db      = redis.createClient(),
    dbCo    = coRedis(db);

module.exports = dbCo;` (in a separate file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't yield `save('bar')` because [SAVE](http://redis.io/commands/save) is synchronous. (Are you sure you want to use save?)

Since it's synchronous, you should change this:

```
exports.home = function *(next){
  yield save('bar')
}
```

to this:

```
exports.home = function *(next){
  save('bar')
}
```

and it will block execution until it's finished.

Almost all other Redis methods are asynchronous, so you would need to `yield` them.

For example:

```
exports.home = function *(next){
  var result = yield redis.set('foo', 'bar')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So I should never use yield in this case? What if instead I would like to do a `var res = get('foo'); this.body=res`? Don't I need the yield on the call, too?

Comment: You need to yield asynchronous functions (which is most of Redis' API). I think that `save` being synchronous (a special case) is what's confusing you. Since Redis' GET is async, then you would yield it: `var res = yield redis.get('foo')`. I only knew that redis.save was synchronous because it says it in bold letters on the documentation page: http://redis.io/commands/save. It's kind of like the difference between Node's `var text = fs.readFileSync('README.md')` (sync) vs `fs.readFile('README.md', function(text) { ... })` (async). Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yield is supposed to be used inside a generator function according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).
The purpose is to return the result of an iteration to be used in the next iteration.

Like in this example (taken from the documentation):

```
function* foo(){
  var index = 0;
  while (index <= 2) // when index reaches 3, 
                     // yield's done will be true 
                     // and its value will be undefined;
    yield index++;
}

var iterator = foo();
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value:0, done:false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value:1, done:false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value:2, done:false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value:undefined, done:true }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the function call is actually inside a generator function, just forgot to write it. Please check my edit.